# SAS: Loop over dataset, make temp data step for ith row, do some proc w/ temp data, return results to first dataset

Tags: sas

So I have a `dataset_a` that looks like this:

```
Name  Month
Dick  Aug
Dick  Sep
Dick  Oct
Jane  Aug
Jane  Sep
...
```

And some other, much larger `dataset_b` like this:

```
Name  Day        X     Y
Dick  12-Jul-13  14.8  2.3
Jane  05-Sep-13  12.2  2.0
Dick  02-Aug-13  15.1  3.2
Dick  07-Aug-13  14.5  3.0
Jane  05-Aug-13  12.8  2.5
Dick  08-Aug-13  14.5  3.0
Dick  10-Aug-13  13.5  2.3
Jane  31-Jul-13  13.0  2.2
...
```

I want to iterate over it, and for each row in `dataset_a`, do a data step that gets the appropriate records from `dataset_b` and puts them in a temp dataset--`temp`, let's call it. Then I need to do a `proc reg` on `temp` and stick the results (row-vector-style) back into `dataset_a`, like so:

```
Name  Month Parameter-est.-for-Y p-value  R-squared
Dick  Aug   Some #               Some #   Some #
Dick  Sep   Some #               Some #   Some #
Dick  Oct   Some #               Some #   Some #
Jane  Aug   Some #               Some #   Some #
Jane  Sep   Some #               Some #   Some #
...
```

Here's some code/pseudocode to illustrate my need:

```
for each row in dataset_a
    data temp;
    set dataset_b; where name=['i'th name] and month(day)=['i'th month]; 
    run;
    proc reg /*noprint*/ alpha=0.1 outest=[?] tableout; model X = Y; run;
    /*somehow put these regression results back into 'i'th row of dataset_a*/
next
```

Please post a comment if something doesn't make sense. Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The efficient approach for this is somewhat different than what you are listing.  In the particular instance you show, the most efficient approach would be to use a format to group the Day values into Months, and run your regression `by name day`, assuming regression respects formats (if not, then create a new variable `month` and assign that using the format).

For example:

```
data for_reg/view=for_reg;
set dataset_b;
month=put(day,MONNAME3.);
run;
```

Or

```
proc datasets lib=work;
modify dataset_b;
format day MONNAME3.;
quit;
```

Then

```
proc reg data=for_reg;
by name month; *or if using the other one, by name day;
**other proc reg statements**;
run;
```

Then merge that output dataset with `dataset_a` if needed.  It will run the proc reg as if you'd run it once for each name/month combination, but all in one call and one pass through the data.

---

If `PROC REG` doesn't respect by groups (and I think it does, but who knows), the best solution is still to do something like this; write a macro to run the proc reg taking arguments of `name` and `month`, and call the macro from the `dataset_a`. Then generate common output files (or `proc append` them into a single master output dataset in the macro) and merge the result to `dataset_a` if needed at the end.

Something like

```
%macro run_procreg(name=,month=);
data for_run/view=for_run;
set dataset_b;
where name=&name. and put(day,MONNAME3.)=&month.;
run;

proc reg data=for_run; 
*other stuff*;
output out=tempdataset; *or however you create your output;
run;

proc append base=master_output data=tempdataset force;
run;
%mend run_procreg;

proc sql;
select cats('%run_procreg(name=',name,',month=',month,')') into :macrocalllist
  separated by ' ' from dataset_a;
quit;

&macrocalllist;

data fin;
merge dataset_a (in=a) master_output(in=b);
by name month;
run;
```

You probably don't need to merge on `dataset_a` at the end if it just has those two variables.  This will be a lot slower than one call with `by`, but if it's necessary, this is the way to do it.

You can also use `call execute` in the datastep to drive a macro list like above - that's nearly the most similar concept to your stated pseudocode, it's almost identical - but it doesn't return the information back to the data step (it executes after the data step completes), and it's slightly more troublesome than the above method.  There is also, in 9.3+, `dosubl` in the FCMP language which allows you to do a bit closer to what you want, but I don't know it well enough to explain or know that it does indeed meet your needs.

Comment: This is a great help. I appreciate that you showed two approaches, as well as hinting at the FCMP route, which I've bumped into in my searches a bit but haven't yet wrapped my head around. Great stuff!